# Why newly created database from Snowflake web console is not listing in snowsql client?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please advice regarding below issue. I am new to Snowflake and learning and doing hands on. I created a new warehouse and database from Snowflake web-console under account admin role. I am trying to connect to SnowSQL client to stage my local files.I was able to connect successfully to SnowSQL and to new warehouse. But my new database which I created from Snowflake console is not listing in SnowSQL client. The database in console shows as `accountadmin` as role. So still not sure why it is not listing in SnowSQL CLI. Please advice?

Thanks,
Tanveer

Comment: Are you under the right role in SnowSQL?  use role accountadmin;   show databases;

Answer (score 0):

Great to see you are learning Snowflake. I would suggest creating a role and then "grant role sysadmin to role yourrole.  Use the same role in snowsql and you should any object created with that role.  As Suzy mentioned, if the role you are using when logging into snowsql has not been granted the role of accountadmin, you will not see the tables created by accountadmin.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for quick response. You both are correct. As I mentioned, in snowflake console I created the DB and tables from accountadmin role whereas in snowsql default role is sysadmin (I was unaware of this).So changed the role to sysadmin in snow sql to account admin role and it worked fine. And tried granting necessary priviliedge to sysadmin role in webconsole and that worked too. thanks a lot once again. Am closing this post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to both of you for quick response. You both are correct. As I mentioned, in snowflake console I created the DB and tables from accountadmin role whereas in snowsql default role is sysadmin (I was unaware of this).So changed the role to sysadmin in snow sql to account admin role and it worked fine. And tried granting necessary priviliedge to sysadmin role in webconsole and that worked too. thanks a lot once again. Am closing this post.